# Give an example of the following

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Give an example of a decreasing function {$f_n$} of continuous functions on [0,1) that converges to a continuous limit function $f$, but the convergence is not uniform.

So far all my attempts either ends up in a discontinuous $f$ or the function is not decreasing.

Any help or insight is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure your statement is true?

Comment: Didn't you mean decreasing sequence $\{f_n\}$ instead of decreasing function $\{f_n\}$ ?

Comment: $f_n(x) = x^n$.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a sequence of function $(f_n)$ converging to $f:x\mapsto \frac{1}{x-1}$, defined in the following way : for $n \in \mathbb{N}$,

$$f_n\ \colon\ 
x\longmapsto\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x-1}&\text{if $0 \le x \le 1-\frac{1}{n+1}$}\\
-(n+1)&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

All functions are defined on $[0,1)$. The $f_n$ and $f$ are continuous, and the decreasing sequence $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to $f$, but the convergence is not uniform because the $f_n$ are bounded and $f$ is not.